# background-position not displaying correctly on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, mobile, background-image, background-position

```
.icon { 
    background: #F0F0F0 url('../images/assets/user.png') no-repeat center left 10px; 
    background-size: 24px 24px;
    -webkit-background-size: 24px 24px;  
}
```

The above CSS works fine in all of the major browsers, but when I view it on any mobile device (HTC, Sony Ericson, Samsung, iPhone etc) the background CSS does not display, not even the color of the background. However, when I remove the `10px` in the `background-position` style - it all works.

I have tried replacing `10px` with `em` and `%` but it doesn't help the case. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `background` property can only take a horizontal and vertical position—in your case `center` andd `10px`—but you have specified three position values. This is why it works when you remove the third value.

Comment: It works with the third value in browsers on computer, but not browsers on mobile ... for some reason. What the third value (10px) does is to offset the position vertically.

Comment: Yes, because you have already set two horizontal values (center and left) which are conflicting. You can only use either `center 10px` or `left 10px`.